# Quartz scheduler not starting

Tags: spring-boot, quartz

I have seen this question being posted multiple times, going back as far as 7 years but no proper answer has been posted so I am getting a little desperate.

I saw some posts in which the answer implied that the issue was with the jobs already scheduled.  So I deleted my quartz database and recreated it.  Even then when I start the springboot REST service, I get the following message in the log;

> 2022-04-18 18:44:15.091  INFO 19884 --- [  restartedMain]
> org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : Scheduler meta-data: Quartz
> Scheduler (v2.3.2) 'quartzScheduler' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
> Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
> NOT STARTED.   Currently in standby mode.   Number of jobs executed: 0
> Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 5
> threads.   Using job-store
> 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore' -
> which supports persistence. and is not clustered.

Does anybody have any idea.

I have no specific quartz specific configuration in my project.